# Django pagination didn't work in my search results page

Tags: html, django, pagination

I just tried to add paginator for my search results page but it didn't work. I have 10 articles in search results and I set 3 for each page, which means totally the results list will be divided into 4 pages. However, when I searched keywords, it showed all 10 articles in the same page and the paginator didn't work.

My **view.py** is:

```
def search_titles(request):
q = request.GET.get('q')
error_msg = ''

if not q:
    error_msg = 'Please enter keywords!'
    return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'error_msg': error_msg})
else:
    nq = q.split(' ')
    a_list = Q(article_ti__icontains=nq[0]) | Q(article_content__icontains=nq[0]) | Q(
        abstract__icontains=nq[0]) | Q(
        author__icontains=nq[0])
    for i in nq[1:]:
        a_list.add(Q(article_ti__icontains=i) | Q(article_content__icontains=i) | Q(abstract__icontains=i) | Q(author__icontains=i), a_list.connector)
    queryset = Article.objects.filter(a_list).distinct()
    queryset_count = queryset.count()

    paginator = Paginator(queryset, 3)
    page_var = 'page'
    page = request.GET.get(page_var, 1)
    try:
        sets = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        sets = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        sets = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

return render(request, 'search_results.html', {'error_msg': error_msg, 'b_list': queryset, 'a_list_count': queryset_count, 'sets': sets, 'page_var':page_var})
```

my **HTML** code is:

```
<div class="ui text container">
    {% if error_msg %}
        <p>{{ error_msg }}</p>
    {% else %}
        {% for a in b_list %}
            <div class="ui segment">
                <a  target="_blank" href={{ a.get_abs_url }}>
                    <h3>{{ a.article_ti }}</h3>
                    <h5>{{ a.author }}</h5>
                    <p>{{ a.abstract }}</p>
                </a>
            </div>
    {% empty %}
        <div class="ui segment">No results for '{{ request.GET.q }}'</div>
    {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
</div>

<div class="pagination" id="m">
<span class="step-links">
    {% if sets.has_previous %}
        <a href="?{{ page_var }}=1&q={{ request.GET.q }}" title="First"><<</a>
        <a href="?{{ page_var }}={{ sets.previous_page_number }}&q={{ request.GET.q }}" title="Previous"><</a>
    {% endif %}

    <span class="current"><input name="enter_page" value="{{ sets.number }}" id="page_num"> of {{ sets.paginator.num_pages }}</span>

    {% if sets.has_next %}
        <a href="?{{ page_var }}={{ sets.next_page_number }}&q={{ request.GET.q }}" title="Next">></a>
        <a href="?{{ page_var }}={{ sets.paginator.num_pages }}&q={{ request.GET.q }}" title="Last">>></a>
    {% endif %}
</span>
</div>
```

I tried several methods on stackoverflow but still no work. Could anyone give me some suggestions?

I'll be very appreciated if you can help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your template your are looping over 'b_list',

```
{% for a in b_list %}
        <div class="ui segment">
            <a  target="_blank" href={{ a.get_abs_url }}>
                <h3>{{ a.article_ti }}</h3>
                <h5>{{ a.author }}</h5>
                <p>{{ a.abstract }}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
{% empty %}
    <div class="ui segment">No results for '{{ request.GET.q }}'</div>
{% endfor %}
```

change this to,

```
{% for a in sets %}
        <div class="ui segment">
            <a  target="_blank" href={{ a.get_abs_url }}>
                <h3>{{ a.article_ti }}</h3>
                <h5>{{ a.author }}</h5>
                <p>{{ a.abstract }}</p>
            </a>
        </div>
{% empty %}
    <div class="ui segment">No results for '{{ request.GET.q }}'</div>
{% endfor %}
```